# Given three lines, determine a fourth which is perpendicular to the other three

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

The problem I have been working with asks us to find a fourth vector line perpendicular to the given vector lines:

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbf{r}(t_1) &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 + 2t_1 \\ t_1 \\ -3 + 2t_1 \end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align*}$$
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbf{q}(t_2) &= \begin{bmatrix} t_2 \\ t_2 \\ t_2 \end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align*}$$
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbf{w}(t_3) &= \begin{bmatrix} 2\\ t_3 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align*}$$

I worked out the direction vector perpendicular to each direction vector by using dot product.

$$d =  (1,0,-1)$$

I am not sure how to determine the complete parametric form of the line. Any tips? Thank you

Comment: Figured it. Find the two closest points on two of the 3 skew lines and the fourth must go through there as at that point the angles are perpendicular. (closest distance between lines.)

Comment: Please check my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the three lines are given by

$ p(t_1) = p_0 + t_1 v_1 $

$ q(t_2) = q_0 + t_2 v_2 $

$ r(t_3) = r_0 + t_3 v_3 $

and that there exists constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that

$ v_3 = \alpha v_1 + \beta v_2 $

Then define $ v_4 = v_1 \times v_2 $, then $v_4$ will be perpendicular to $v_1$ and to $v_2$ and also to $v_3$.  Thus we now have the line

$ s(t_4) = s_0 + t_4 v_4 $

We want $s(t_4)$ to intersect $p(t_1) , q(t_2) , r(t_3) $ at three different values of $t_4$, let's call them $t_4, t_5, t_6$, so we now have

$ s_0 + t_4 v_4 = p_0 + t_1 v_1 $

$ s_0 + t_5 v_4 = q_0 + t_2 v_2 $

$ s_0 + t_6 v_4 = r_0 + t_3 v_3 $

From the first equation, we have

$ s_0 = p_0 + t_1 v_1 - t_4 v_4 $

Substituting in the other two equations

$ p_0 + t_1 v_1 + (t_5 - t_4 ) v_4 = q_0 + t_2 v_2 $

$ p_0 + t_1 v_1 + (t_6 - t_4) v_4 = r_0 + t_3 v_3 $

This gives the linear system

$ A t = b $

where

$A = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 && - v_2 && 0 && - v_4 && v_4 && 0 \\ v_1  && 0 && - v_3 && - v_4 && 0 && v_4 \end{bmatrix} $

and

$ b = \begin{bmatrix} q_0 - p_0 \\ r_0 - p_0 \end{bmatrix} $

And

$ t = [t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4, t_5, t_6 ]^T $

Note that $A$ is a $6 \times 6$ matrix.

If this system has a solution, then it is possible to pass a fourth line through the three given lines, with it being perpendicular to them.

Comment: So what was the mistake in your previous answer, when you concluded that there were no solutions?

Comment: Before correcting it, I had too few unknowns (the $t$'s)

Comment: thank you for your clear answer! Appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

The direction vectors of $\mathbf{r}(t_1)$ and $ \mathbf{q}(t_2) $ and $ \mathbf{w}(t_3) $ are linearly dependent, because

$(2, 1, 2) = 2 (1, 1, 1) - (0, 1, 0) $

Hence if we find a vector that is perpendicular to $(1,1,1)$ and to $(0, 1, 0) $ then it will be perpendicular to $(2, 1, 2) $

This perpendicular vector is $(0, 1, 0) \times (1,1,1) = (1, 0, -1) $

As you found out.  Now we want to find where to place this fourth line.  It has to intersect all three lines.  The fourth line is therefore

$ \mathbf{u}(t_4) = (1, 0, -3) + t_1 (2, 1, 2) + t_4 (1, 0, -1) $

Now we have to do two things.  We have to equate this to $\mathbf{q}(t_2)$ and to $\mathbf{w}(t_3) $, so we will have,

$ (1, 0, -3) + t_1 (2, 1, 2) + t_4 (1, 0, -1) = t_2 (1, 1, 1) $

and

$ (1, 0, -3) + t_1 (2, 1, 2) + t_5 (1, 0, -1) = (2, 0, 0) + t_3 (0, 1, 0) $

These two vector equations will give us the following equations

$ 1+ 2 t_1 + t_4 = t_2 $

$ t_1 = t_2 $

$ -3 + 2 t_1 - t_4 = t_2 $

$ 1 + 2 t_1 + t_5 = 2 $

$ t_1 = t_3 $

$ -3 + 2 t_1 - t_5  = 0 $

The solution is

$(t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4, t_5) = (1, 1,1, -2, -1) $

Therefore, the fourth line passes through

$ (1, 0, -3) + t_1 (2,1,2) = (1, 0, -3) + (1)(2,1,2) = (3, 1, -1) $

which also lies on the first line.

The fourth line intersection with the second line is

$(1, 0, -3) + t_1 (2, 1, 2) + t_4 (1, 0, -1) = (1, 1, 1) $

And finally the fourth line intersection with the third line is

$ (1, 0, -3) + t_1 (2, 1, 2) + t_5 (1, 0, -1) = (2, 0, 0) + t_3 (0, 1, 0) = ( 2, 1, 0) $

Comment: Since it is a linear composition if you find a vector orthogonal to two lines it must be orthogonal to the third line. Given any two skew vectors, you can always find an orthogonal line going through them, therefore there must exist a line and a unique solution. You contradict your answer and there is a mistake.

Comment: There is a difference between vector and line.  There exists a vector which is perpendicular to the direction vectors of the three lines. But this doesn't mean that you can find a line with that perpendicular direction which passes through the three lines.

Comment: See my answer @Hosam H

Answer (score 0):

Having worked out the fourth line's direction vector as $(1,0,-1)$, let us determine the two closest points on $\mathbf{r}(t_1)$ and $\mathbf{q}(t_2)$. Consider the vector between the two closest points e.i. $$(-1,0,3) + (t_2 - 2t_1, t_2 - t_1, t_2 - 2t_1)$$
Now let us consider the dot product with the direction vectors of $\mathbf{r}(t_1)$ and $\mathbf{q}(t_2)$. We arrive at this system of equations.

$$-5t_1 + 3t_2 = -2$$
$$-9t_1 + 5t_2 = -4$$

Solving this yields $t_1 = 1$ and plugging it into $\mathbf{r}(t_1)$ we find a point $P = (3,1,-1)$

The fourth vector will go through this point and have the determined vector. As illustrated below.[image: Green vector]

Comment: You're considering two lines out of three.  Whar about the third line?

Comment: Consider the second and third lines, then we can see that the lines are coinciding, thus either point would give the correct equation for the fourth line.

Comment: @HosamH I believe there should be general proof for this when we have linearly dependent vectors. But I am not sure how to show it more easily.

Comment: Please check my new solution.  I've considered the general case.