# Determining the fourth vector line which is orthogonal to the other three vector lines in space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality

I have a hard time conceptually understanding what I have to do. I am aware that I can consider the direction vectors and that by dot product I can determine the direction vector of a line perpendicular to all the other 3 vector lines. The problem arises when I have to determine the point which determines such a fourth line or to establish if such a point even exists. This is linked to my previous question as I do not quite understand my solution, as this is not a general solution for all vectors. Is there even a way to determine that?

Thank you for any tips or insights! I linked my previous question below. :)

[Given three lines, determine a fourth which is perpendicular to the other three](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4792245/given-three-lines-determine-a-fourth-which-is-perpendicular-to-the-other-three)

Comment: Generally you will not be able to find a fourth direction vector perpendicular to three fixed direction vectors in three dimensional space.  This should already have been brought out in answers to your previous Question.

Comment: @hardmath What would have to be the conditions for it to be possible?

Comment: The three fixed vectors would have to be linearly dependent.  Some knowledge of linear algebra is key to understanding why, but the three equations of orthogonality given *homogeneous* equations for the fourth vector's components (dot product zero as you seem to have surmised).  In three dimensional space the direction vectors have three components, so three equations for three unknowns.  But the equations have zero on the right hand side, so a nontrivial solution amounts to a linear dependence relation among the three fixed vectors.